# how to call dealloc method

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone development.
I am calling one viewController on my button click event. But when I come back, my `-dealloc` method is not called. Here is my code of button click event:

```
-(IBAction)btnAddPressed:(id)sender
{
    FriendsTableListViewController *viewController = [[FriendsTableListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FriendsTableListViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    [viewController release];
}
```

Here is my dealloc method of viewController where i was after clicked on button:

```
-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I don't know why dealloc method is not working properly. Please help me. Thanking you...

Comment: What version are you using for the Xcode and iOS ?

Comment: Do you call delegates or properties, you may have a property that retains the FriendsTableListViewController, you may have a property that is still retaining an instance of FriendsTableListViewController

Comment: How do you know it isn't being called? FWIW, the OS can call it quite a bit later than you have released an object. Best thing to do is to try to avoid `-dealloc` altogether and instead use [ARC](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1).

Comment: here dealloc method will not be called only viewwillAppear and viewDidAppear method will be called. it will be called after when viewDidUnLoad method is called. Understand View Life Cycle throughly

Comment: calls to dealloc is done solely by the iOS at its own time during garbage collection. It doesnt automatically mean that the dealloc is called just when an object is release. And I am not sure what you mean by "dealloc is not working properly". Plus if you are not doing much in there why not remove the whol method and let the super class handle deallocation?

Comment: *DO NOT* call `dealloc`, and if you don't want to deal with memory management, use ARC

Comment: i am asking this question because i tried this one also:stackoverflow.com/questions/10713939/memory-management-on-back but could not get any proper answer...so could you help me ,i will be thankful...

Comment: Your dealloc method is working properly. Why are you so desperate to see it in action? Accept nhahtdh as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The navigationController is holding on to your controller (it will take ownership when you push your view controller), so it will not be deallocated.

If you want to remove the view controller, pop it out of the navigation controller.

Comment: i am asking this question because i tried this one also:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713939/memory-management-on-back
but could not get any proper answer...so could you help me ,i will be thankful...

Comment: Have you tried my approach? And as @xlc0212 suggested, convert your project to ARC.

Comment: sorry my friend..i can't because my boss told me that we will not covert to ARC in any cost...now tell me what should i do?